# Ionic 2 / Angular 2 Routing - Progressive Web App

Tags: ionic-framework, routes, ionic2

I'm searching the web to find a solution to implement url routing in Ionic2, I can't seem to find a way to access a page using a URL.

1. Has it been implemented in Ionic 2?
2. Should the Angular 2 router be used? Does it work with Ionic 2?

I need to be able to get the physical url of a page within the web app; in order to be able to share it outside the web app.

Thank you,

Answer (score 7):

I think you are looking for the Ionic service DeepLinker. That does not replace the FILO/NavController but provide a way to define and display specific views based on URLs.

In your main module add:

```
imports: [
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {}, {
      links: [
         { component: DetailPage, name: 'Detail', segment: 'detail/:userId' }
     ]
  })
]
```

The [full documentation here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/2.2.0/api/navigation/DeepLinker/).

Also, if you also release your PWA on the AppStore/Play Store, you can use the native plugin [Ionic Deeplinks](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/ionic-deeplinks/).

Comment: Thank  you! Will take a closer look at this :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Ionic 2 uses a pile FILO schema for routing with his NavController methods ( like `push`, `pop`, `setRoot`). And you don't need to use a sequence for it like you would do with a Routing system, like to access page 2 i need to go through page 0 and 1, you can just `push(NewPage)` and it will work, so it gives you a much better control over your application pages and how they interact.
2. I've never seen anyone talking about using it. If the NavController uses the Angular 2 routing in its background i don't know, will search for this, but the Ionic NavController is easy to use and works very good on most cases, the only case it doesn't support yet is passing parameters back within his `pop()` method, for this i use a modal and style it totally like a normal page. You can also use `setRoot` instead of `pop` to pass data like so.

   ```
   this.navCtrl.setRoot(MyPage, this.Data);
   ```

For more information please see the [ionic 2 documentation on navigation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation)

Comment: Thank you Gabriel and Gardi for this answer. So at this stage, it's not possible to "share" a url to a specific page right? In case of PWA